# largest possible in memory array of non integer numbers in C#

Tags: c#

Looking at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420(v=vs.60).aspx), it appears that Single is the non integer number with the lowest memory requirements in C#. If I create:

```
Single[,] data = new Single[100000000, 10];
```

I am getting a:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException
```

Does this depend on my machine's available RAM? Could I keep an array like this or larger in memory? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it depends on your available RAM. You should keep in mind that your array would be the size 40 GB if my calculations are correct.

Comment: So you also need to look into [`<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Crowcoder OP is talking about _non integer number_

Comment: Thanks. Just set platform target to x64 .. still the same.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, thx, missed that

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - thanks I read this but as pointed out by Damien it may be possible to lift the 2GB limit: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - see also answer by nvoigt

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - you are mistaken to claim that this is already answered ...

Comment: @csetzkorn You're right...

Comment: If so please remove duplicate highlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this depend on my machine's available RAM?

To an extent, yes. You cannot have an object that is significantly larger than your memory. **However:**

> Could I keep an array like this or larger in memory?

32bit processes can be 2GB in size maximum (3GB with special exceptions). But even on 64bit systems using a 64bit process, [you cannot exceed the size of 2 GB for a single .NET object](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joshwil/2005/08/10/bigarrayt-getting-around-the-2gb-array-size-limit/). So you can have two large arrays of 1.5 GB each, but you could not have a single one of 3 GB. And yours seems to be way above that size.

---

As commenters pointed out, [there is a way around this limit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx) with later editions of .NET:

Put this in your App.config file:

```
<configuration>  
  <runtime>  
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />  
  </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: Note that article you linked is 12 year old. Now there is a way to allocate objects larger than 2GB.

Comment: Well, you can use [`<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx) to allow objects greater than 2GB in size.

Comment: @Evk Thanks, added it.

Comment: Wow this works for the example. i chose. Bit confused now how, as I definitely do not have 40GB of RAM ... must be magic.

Comment: @csetzkorn See [Virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). Note that just declaring the array only reserves space for it in virtual memory. Only when you start setting values in it will the memory actually be commited. Try initialising it in a loop and watch your program slow to a crawl... ;)

Comment: @MatthewWatson - seeded it with random number and use NCalc against it work fairly fast.

Comment: @csetzkorn In my head, your array is only 3.8 GB. But I am known for not doing great calculating large numbers in my head, so better check it twice.

Comment: Yeah it's only 3GB. :) So it won't be very slow. If it really was 40GB then it would be significantly slower!